# Is it possible to have a workspace variable that persists across a call to clear?

Tags: matlab

Suppose I run a script `X.m` and it creates a bunch of variables, and I want to save a variable called `Z`, so I write `myVar = Z`.

I then type `clear` at the prompt, and run `Y.m`.

Is there a way I can make it so that `myVar` does not disappear with all the other variables when I call `clear`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use [`clearvars`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clearvars.html) to clear all variables except specific ones from workspace. From `clearvars` documentation:

> clearvars -except v1 v2 ... clears all variables except for those
>   specified following the -except flag. Use the wildcard character '*'
>   in a variable name to exclude variables that match a pattern from
>   being cleared. clearvars -except X* clears all the variables in the
>   current workspace, except for those that start with X, for instance.
>   Use clearvars -except to keep the variables you want and remove all
>   others.

So, you need to type

```
clearvars -except myVars
```

instead of `clear`.

Answer (score 3):

There's [Keep](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7129-keep4) on the MATLAB file exchange which lets you clear everything except certain variables that you wish to keep.