# variable becomes undeclared after some iteration in matlab

Tags: matlab, memory

[Does MATLAB keep some variables after clearing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477918/does-matlab-keep-some-variables-after-clearing)

[Matlab: Free memory is lost after calling a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300161/matlab-free-memory-is-lost-after-calling-a-function/3301971#3301971)

My question is related to this post but some changes are there.

I have to use the output (the outputs are matrices generated, i.e. i am generating small matrices in every iteration) produced by previous large program, in my next iteration of large program, so when i am using the technique mentioned in the post, i am getting error that " Reference to a cleared variable", i need to keep some of the variables and some matrices generated. How to do that?

Sometimes the error occurs after 1 iteration only

Thanks

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15565396/is-it-possible-to-have-a-workspace-variable-that-persists-across-a-call-to-clear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear specific variables in the workspace with:

```
clear myvarname
```

You can also clear functions that might be holding `persistent` variables with:

```
clear myfunname
```

So - you should work out which ones you don't want (type `whos` to see variables in the workspace, or in a breakpoint) and clear the ones you don't need.

Another option would be to `save` the ones you do want, use the clear method you mentioned, then re-`load`.